# Mail app is not working in Odin

Tags: pantheon-mail, release-odin

I tried login my email accounts in the Mail app in EOS Odin. But was unable to sign in to any of the accounts I use. I tried Zoho Mail and Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

gmail works, i have 2 accounts on with odin.
what password are you typing for the login info? your gmail acc or the one google give to access mail client?

Comment: Oh! Nice. I tried first with Goggle password, but it didn't work. Then, I created the app password to login, but that also failed. However, I was to add Google calendar in the calendar app using the app password.

Comment: Rather strange, I had a connection problem when creating the account on Mail with Odin but I reiterated and the connection was made with this google application pass.
Just create a third account with via imap and the google applications pass, so, idk where is the problem.